# Genshi pluralisation

Tags: python, genshi

Anyone know how I could show `entry/entries` as appropriate, in the following fragment of Genshi syntax?

```
  <span py:if="c.page.item_count">
    ${c.page.item_count} entries.
  </span>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not pretty, but should work

```
<span py:if="c.page.item_count">
  ${c.page.item_count} ${['entries','entry'][c.page.item_count==1]}.
</span>
```

or

```
<span py:if="c.page.item_count">
  ${c.page.item_count} ${'entry' if c.page.item_count==1 else 'entries'}.
</span>
```